# Insert into a table based on a cursor

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor

I have the below tables:

Table1:

```
    | Resp_ID | Description |
    |       1 |          AA |
    |       2 |          AA |
    |       3 |          AA |
```

Table 2:

```
    | ORG_ID  | Resp_ID |        Date | GID |
    |    001  |       1 |   08-SEP-14 | 112 |
    |    002  |       1 |   08-SEP-14 | 112 |
    |    003  |       3 |   08-SEP-14 | 114 |
    |    004  |       5 |   08-SEP-14 |     |
    |    005  |       5 |   08-SEP-14 |     |
    |    006  |       6 |   08-SEP-14 |     |
```

My requirement is like this:
I need to insert GID into Table2 if Resp_ID in Table2 is not found in Table1.

Hence I wrote the below script but it doesn't work:

```
    DECLARE
      CURSOR resp_id_cursor
      IS
        SELECT resp_id
        FROM   Table1
        WHERE  description LIKE '%AA%';

        flag NUMBER;

    BEGIN
       FOR resp_cur IN resp_id_cursor
         SELECT 1
         INTO   flag
         FROM   Table2 a
         WHERE  a.resp_id = resp_cur.resp_id;

         IF flag != 1 THEN
           INSERT INTO Table2 (GID) 
           VALUES(115);
         END IF;
       END LOOP;
     END;
     /
```

Please advice.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this code,

```
declare  

        cursor r1 is
     SELECT Resp_ID 
     FROM Table2;

   gid1 number:= 115;
    flag number:=0;
   begin

   FOR c1 in r1
   LOOP
     begin
   dbms_output.put_line('in here');
   SELECT count(*)
         INTO   flag
         FROM   Table1 a
         WHERE  a.Resp_ID  = c1.Resp_ID ;
         dbms_output.put_line('flag is '||flag);
   dbms_output.put_line( c1.Resp_ID );
         IF (flag = 0) THEN
         dbms_output.put_line('doesnt exist');
     update Table2 set gid=gid1 where Resp_ID =c1.Resp_ID ;     
        dbms_output.put_line('update value for Resp_ID  '||c1.Resp_ID );
         dbms_output.put_line('gid inserted is  '||gid1);
     flag:=0;
     commit;
     dbms_output.put_line('commited');
         END IF;

       exception
       when no_Data_found then
         dbms_output.put_line('no data found for Resp_ID  '||c1.Resp_ID );
         end;
       gid1:=gid1+1;
   END LOOP;

   END;
```

Comment: thanks! i modified your code according to my more details specs and it is working fine!

Answer (score 0):

Count(*) will not raise exception. You should try like this:

```
DECLARE 
CURSOR resp_id_cursor IS SELECT resp_id FROM Table1 WHERE description LIKE '%AA%'; 
flag NUMBER; 
Gid_ number;
BEGIN 
 Select max(gid) into gid_ from table2;
 FOR resp_cur IN resp_id_cursor loop
   Begin
     SELECT 1 INTO flag FROM Table2 a
       WHERE a.resp_id = resp_cur.resp_id;
  Exception when no_data_found then
   Gid_:=gid_+1;
    INSERT INTO Table2 (GID) VALUES(gid_); 
  End;
 END LOOP; 
END; 
/
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can generate a result set from Table2 exposing the a key field, the field you want updated and the value you want it updated to, Oracle allows this form of the `Update` statement:

```
update (
    select  t2.Resp_ID, t2.GID, 115 as NewGID
    from    Table2 t2
    left join Table1 t1
        on  t1.Resp_ID = t2.Resp_ID
    where   t1.Resp_ID is null
)
    set GID = NewGid;
```

**NOTE**: There is one strange aspect of this statement. When I write SQL code, I like to place the opening parenthesis of a substatement abut the last character of the previous line.

```
join(
    <subquery>
) alias
```

So I would prefer to start the `update` statement above like this:

```
update(
```

However, for the `Update` statement, there must be at least one space between `update` and the parenthesis or the statement generates an "ORA-00933 - SQL command not properly ended" error. So the space between "update" and "(" is not accidental. Many developers place the parenthesis at the beginning of the next line, so this is not a problem for them. If your preferences are like mine, be aware.